# Cybereason - Failed to connect using proxy policy Direct

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

We are experiencing an issue when trying to connect a virtual machine which is in Azure to our on-prem servers, we already enabled the outbound firewall rule to communicate through the port 443.

```
7149 INFO 2022-06-10_19:13:53 StreamEngine.cpp:217 **Connecting to 35.229.107.243:443**
7150 INFO 2022-06-10_19:13:53 MultiProxyEngine.cpp:72 *****Failed to connect using proxy policy Direct**
7151 WARNING 2022-06-10_19:13:53 TcpTransport.cpp:177 LOG_TIMED hit count: 1 Connect timed out, network error or resolve fails. Waiting 300 seconds for reconnection.
7152 WARNING 2022-06-10_19:13:53 TcpTransport.cpp:179 **LOG_TIMED hit count: 1 **Error details: stream truncated category: asio.ssl.stream****
7153 WARNING 2022-06-10_19:14:00 ConfigurationManager.cpp:112 **external requested DB empty, scheduling sync**
7154 INFO 2022-06-10_19:14:15 CapabilitiesUtils.cpp:47 DB: capabilities - **Failed to read capabilities values, the DB is probably empty**
7155 INFO 2022-06-10_19:14:15 CapabilitiesUtils.cpp:47 DB: capabilities - Failed to read capabilities values, the DB is probably empty
7156 INFO 2022-06-10_19:14:15 CapabilitiesUtils.cpp:47 DB: capabilities - Failed to read capabilities values, the DB is probably empty
7157 INFO 2022-06-10_19:14:15 CapabilitiesUtils.cpp:47 DB: capabilities - Failed to read capabilities values, the DB is probably empty
7158 INFO 2022-06-10_19:14:15 CapabilitiesUtils.cpp:47 DB: capabilities - Failed to read capabilities values, the DB is probably empty
7159 INFO 2022-06-10_19:14:15 CapabilitiesUtils.cpp:47 DB: capabilities - Failed to read capabilities values, the DB is probably empty
7160 INFO 2022-06-10_19:14:15 CapabilitiesUtils.cpp:47 DB: capabilities - Failed to read capabilities values, the DB is probably empty
7161 INFO 2022-06-10_19:14:15 CapabilitiesUtils.cpp:47 DB: capabilities - Failed to read capabilities values, the DB is probably empty
7162 INFO 2022-06-10_19:14:15 CapabilitiesUtils.cpp:47 DB: capabilities - Failed to read capabilities values, the DB is probably empty
7163 WARNING 2022-06-10_19:15:00 ConfigurationManager.cpp:112 external requested DB empty, scheduling sync
```

So, it actually tries to connect to the server, but the negotiation after the connection is when it fails:

```
$ telnet 35.229.107.243 443
Trying 35.229.107.243...
Connected to 35.229.107.243.
Escape character is '^]'.The port is open, however the connection doesn't complete.
```

It connects via the port 443, and the connection is available, but there is some negotiation afterwards that prevents the communication to be completed.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: check this troubleshooting steps that might helps you : https://www.techbout.com/unable-to-connect-to-proxy-server-windows-10-40178/

Comment: Hey, did the suggestion work? do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot. [Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

make sure tls1.2 and 1.3 is enabled and not Inspected

apedr001-r.cybereason.net should able to resolve

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).